# If $\psi(t)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}\varphi(x)dx$ then $\psi\in\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R}) $

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Exercices :
Let $\varphi\in\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R}) $ such that : $\displaystyle\int\limits_\mathbb{R}\varphi (x)dx=0 $

Let defined :
$$\psi(t)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{t}\varphi(x)dx$$
Then prove that :
$\psi\in\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R}) $

---

My attempts:

To prove $\psi\in\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R}) $ We need to prove :
$$q_{m,n}(\psi)=\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|t^ {n}\psi^{(m)}(t)|<+\infty$$
So : $\psi^{(m)}(t)=\varphi^{(m-1)}(t)$

by " liebniz rule "
So :

$$q_{m,n}(\psi)=\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|t^{n}\varphi^{(m-1)}(t)|=q_{m-1,n<p}(\varphi)<+\infty\Rightarrow\psi\in\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R})$$
Is my solution correct? But why give me

$\displaystyle\int\limits_\mathbb{R}\varphi (x)dx=0 ~~???$

---

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|t^{n}\psi^{(m)}(t)|$? – And what is $p$ in $q_{m,n<p}(\psi)$?

Comment: Among other things you need $\psi(t) = 0$ for large enough $t$. This is where $\int \phi = 0$ is needed.

Comment: Sorry ; just a wrong typo

Comment: *Umberto P ooh it's ok " rapidly decreasing functions "

Comment: It is smooth, for $k\ge 1$ the $k$th derivative is rapidly decreasing, so it remains to show that $\psi$ is rapidly decreasing. As $t\to -\infty$ this is because $|\varphi(t)|\le A t^{-n-1}$ gives $|\psi(t)|\le A t^{-n}$. As $t \to +\infty$ it works the same way because $\psi(t)=-\int_t^\infty \varphi(x)dx$.